# Automated Bash Upload Script with Crontab Raspberry Pi Not Running

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi, rsync

I'm attempting to have my Raspberry Pi use rysnc to upload files to an SFTP server sporadically throughout the day. To do so, I created a bash script and installed a crontab to run it every couple hours during the day. If I run the bash script, it works perfectly, but it never seems to run using crontab.

I did the following:

1. "sudo nano upload.sh"
2. Create the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "password" rsync -avh -e ssh /local/directory host.com:/remote/directory
```

3. "sudo chmod +x upload.sh"
4. Test running it with "./upload.sh"

Now, I have tried all the following ways to add it to crontab ("sudo crontab -e")

1. 30 8,10,12,14,16 * * * ./upload.sh
2. 30 8,10,12,14,16 * * * /home/picam/upload.sh
3. 30 8,10,12,14,16 * * * bash /home/picam/upload.sh

None of these work based on the fact that new files are not uploaded. I have another bash script running using method 2 above without issue. I would appreciate any insight into what might be going wrong. I have done this on eight separate Raspberry Pi 3B that are all taking photos throughout the day. The crontab upload works on none of them.

**UPDATE:**
Upon logging the crontab job, I found the following error:

```
Host key verification failed.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(703) [sender=3.2.3]
```

This error also occurred if I tried running my bash script without first connecting to the server via scp and accepting the certificate. How to get around this when calling rsync from crontab?

Comment: Standard cron job troubleshooting: capture the output & errors from the script by adding something like `>>/tmp/upload.log 2>&1` to the crontab entry, let it try to run, then see what the log file shows. Also, cron jobs run with a really minimal environment, including `PATH` -- are all the programs it uses (looks like `sshpass`, `rsync`, and `ssh`) in /bin or /usr/bin?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments Gordon! I've added the logging to see what happens. All of those packages are in /bin -- should they be somewhere else as well?

Comment: Having them in /bin is fine; the potential problem is if they *weren't* there (e.g. if they were in /usr/local/bin or /home/picam/bin or something like that) then a cron job might not be able to find them. BTW, if you need to add the log output, please edit it into the question (rather than putting it in a comment or something like that), and use [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) so it's readable.

Comment: Thank you again Gordon. I've updated the results from logging. Thank you for that tip! Based on this, I will try disabling the host key check in rsync and update with an answer if it works.

Comment: That error suggests the server's host key has changed (or the wrong key is stored in the root account's ~/.ssh/known_hosts file). Similarly, you shouldn't have to keep re-accepting the key when connecting with `scp`. Is there something weird going on with the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to logging recommendation from Gordon Davisson in comments, I was able to identify the problem.

A logging error occurred, as mentioned in the original question update above where rsync would choke on a host key verification.

My solution: tell rsync not to check host key certificates. I simply changed the upload.sh bash file the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p "password" rsync -avh -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /local/directory host.com:/remote/directory
```

Working perfectly now -- hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if the script is working properly at all ( paste it in shell)
2. Check if your crond.service working properly - `systemctl status crond.service`.
   Output should be "**active (running)**"
3. Then you can try add simply test job to cron: `* * * * * echo "test" >> /path/whichyou/want/file.txt`

and check if this job work properly

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I mentioned, script functions fine in shell, I have three python scripts and a bash script running fine in crontab on all eight Raspberry Pis. The problem is this one bash script not running. I've now added log based on Gordon's comment above and will see what happens.